# Can I pass data to a handlebars partial?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I'm making a website in Node JS, and want to display something from the database on the website.

When I fetch the data in node, I pass it of to an html page (an hbs file) using express as the second argument in res.render().
However, that html page (hbs file) which I pass the data to, contains a partial, is it possible to pass that same data which was passed to the hbs file, to the partial that is in that hbs file?

Important code for reference:

Passing the data to the hbs file:

```
app.get('/about',async (req,res)=>{
    const names = await Category.find({});
    res.render('about',{
        categories:names
    });
})
```

Then I'd like to do something like this
`{{>header,{{categories}}}}` in order to access the categories data in the partial.

Comment: If I remember correctly you should be able to access the data in the partial just like an ordinary page doing {{categories}}.  Could you provide the hbs files?

Comment: @DavideTurini You seem to be absolutely spot on. I was on the wrong path apparently, trying to pass it as parameter={{categories}} but all of that was unnecessary. I think it's working, thanks a lot.